# preg_replace character in span tag

Tags: php, regex

I have s string like this

```
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">I want replace this text to other text</span>
<span style="font-size: 18pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">I want replace this text to other text</span>
```

I want to use PHP to make it

```
    <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">I want replace <a href="#">this text</a> to other text</span>
<span style="font-size: 18pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">I want replace this text to other text</span>
```

I want only text have span  style font-size:11pt replace
help me please
Thanks

Comment: and what is the pattern you are following while replacing?

Comment: yes I can try, but you need to specify where to substitute `href`..it cannot be anywhere..there must be some specific point in text where you would want to substitute it

Comment: if text is " I want" after span tag, can you help me

Comment: how much part you want to keep in `href`?

Comment: see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/kJ7jW1/1)**

Comment: but still you need to tell how much part to be kept in `href`?

Comment: i want replace "I want" to "<a > I want</a>" but only in  <span style="font-size:11pt">

Comment: your example above contradicts what you have written..there you have replaced `this text`

Comment: anyway check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/kJ7jW1/2)**..on the site you can see the substitution that has been done in bottom part

Comment: Thanks but if text dymanic it not work
example
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">dymanic change this text dymanic change</span>
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">dymanic change other this text dymanic change</span>

Comment: that's why i am asking time and again which part you wanna change exactly?is it the first two words?

Comment: yes two word, but other word is dymanic, they can change to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments this regex will work

```
((?:.*?<span.*?style\s*=\s*"font-size\s*:\s*11pt[^>]*>))(.+?)(this text)(.*?(?<=<\/span>|$))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ7jW1/6)**

Comment: Thanks i'm edit pattern
/((?:.*<span.*"font-size:\s*11pt[^>]*>))(.+?)(this text)((.+?)<\/span>)/
replacement 
$1$2<a href="#">this text</a>$4

Comment: @LapDam you were only mentioning two words..I assumed them to be from starting..your regex is greedy..see the updated one in my answer

Comment: @Downvoter please do leave a comment before downvoting

Comment: @rock321987: Downvoters are rarely objective when downvoting. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37794065/3832970) downvote. Once OP accepts an answer, I'd always relieve my downvote (unless the answer is just plain wrong and OP made a mistake when accepting it). The worst is when you have a negative score on an accepted answer as you cannot delete it.