# Regex to get only characters without space inside special tags

Tags: php, regex

I have 2 texts in a string:

%Juan%

%Juan Gonzalez%

And I want to only be able to get %Juan% and not the one with the Space, I have been trying several Regexes witout luck. I currently use:

```
/%(.*)%/U
```

but it gets both things, I tried adding and playing with [^\s] but it doesnt works.

Any help please?

Comment: Study character classes.

Comment: I don't know how you _played_ with it but `/%([^\s]+)%/` should work.

Comment: What do you want to capture in this situation: `..................................%Juan% %Juan Gonzalez%michel%herbert philippe%%le_gros_Louis%`? *( Note that "michel" is outside paired `%`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `.` matches any character but a newline. The `/U` ungreedy mode only makes `.*` lazy and it captures a text from the `%` up to the first `%` to the right of the first `%`.

**If your strings contain one pair of `%...%`**, you may use

```
/%(\S+)%/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI2lO5/1)

The `\S+` pattern matches 1+ characters other than a whitespace, and the whole `[^\h%]` negated character class that matches any character but a horizontal space and `%` symbol.

If you have multiple `%...%` pairs, you may use

```
/%([^\h%]+)%/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI2lO5/3), where `\h` matches any horizontal whitespace.

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/dy1TkA):

```
$re = '/%([^\h%]+)%/'; 
$str = "%Juan%\n%Juan Gonzalez%"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```